# Open-Delta 3-phase transformer kVA rating

Tags: transformer, three-phase, delta

I have a V-V three-phase transformer supplying a 50kVA balanced three-phase load. I know that the apparent power of a three-phase transformer \$S_{3\phi} = 3VI^*\$ and that of an open-delta system is \$S_{V-V} = \sqrt3VI^*\$. I don't understand what the 50kVA represents in this case. How can I proceed to find the kVA rating of each transformer?

Comment: By "each transformer" do you mean each phase of the three-phase transformer? That would be 50/3 kVA wouldn't it?

Comment: @Transistor yes that is what I initially assumed, I don't know if I was overcomplicating this

Comment: Each transformer? Do you mean each secondary winding? Please fix your question.

Comment: @Andyaka I simply posed the question the way I received it. I too am unsure.